# Get number of overlapping pixels PHP

Tags: php

What would be the shortest way to get the number of overlapping pixels between two rectangles in PHP if I have their X,Y coordinates and their height/width? This is a bit of a best-practices question since I'm currently doing this with a buggy/messy collection of if statements.

EDIT: This is what I am trying to fix at the moment:

```
echo overlapping(1,1,5,5,4,4,6,6).PHP_EOL;
echo overlapping(0,0,29,21,30,20,40,50).PHP_EOL;
function overlapping($x1,$y1,$w1,$h1,$x2,$y2,$w2,$h2){
$wover = abs($x1+($w1/2)  - ($x2+($w2/2))) - ($w1/2)+ ($w2/2);
$hover = abs($y1+($h1/2)  - ($y2+($h2/2))) - ($h1/2)+ ($h2/2);
return $wover*$hover;
}
```

Comment: Share your buggy collection of if statements,and we will help you imrovise it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo overlapping(0,-1,10,20,30,20,40,50);

function overlapping($x1,$y1,$w1,$h1,$x2,$y2,$w2,$h2){

$wover = abs($x1+($w1/2)  - ($x2+($w2/2))) > ($w1/2)+ ($w2/2)?0:1;

$hover = abs($y1+($h1/2)  - ($y2+($h2/2))) > ($h1/2)+ ($h2/2)?0:1;

if($hover && $wover ){
return 'over';

}
return 'not';

}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ea506fd72f827965d7241d520789a833b34dff5

Comment: I am trying to get the number of pixels instead of bools.

Comment: change '<' to '-' ,del '?0:1' , 

it is overlap area height & width

Comment: `echo overlapping(1,1,5,5,4,4,5,5);
function overlapping($x1,$y1,$w1,$h1,$x2,$y2,$w2,$h2){
$wover = abs($x1+($w1/2)  - ($x2+($w2/2))) - ($w1/2)+ ($w2/2);
$hover = abs($y1+($h1/2)  - ($y2+($h2/2))) - ($h1/2)+ ($h2/2);
return $hover;
}` $wover and $hover both return 3

Comment: $wover and $hover is count of overlap pt ..if value , need  -1